# Python3: Is it possible to make a error not show the line of code that caused the error?

Tags: python, traceback

I want to know *if it's possible* to make a traceback not show the line of code that caused the error.

I don't want:

```
>>> print("hi"f)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("hi"f)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do want:

```
>>> print("hi"f)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Do you really want that to happen when your code is entered at the REPL like your example shows, or is it for a module on-disk where you can have, say, a `.pyo` file but no corresponding `.py`?

Comment: To be clear, it's _possible_ either way -- nothing stops you from writing your own exception handler -- but there's definitely a difference in approach.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to make your software behave in a way that's unexpected, especially if it really adds no value - if you're doing this because you need to keep your code a secret, you should reconsider using Python in the first place, since your code will be distributed with your software anyway. If you're doing this because you want nicer error messages, consider catching exceptions and writing better error messages - or deal with the errors so that an error message isn't even required.

Comment: @Grismar Then you can compile it into a ```.pyc``` file (if you want hidden code and this question is just a answer)

Comment: If you just distribute a `.pyc` (accepting the fact that it will only run on the architecture it was compiled for and only on the same version of Python it was compiled with), the question is pointless because then the error message will actually be exactly what you asked for. (and of course, a `.pyc` is fairly trivial to decompile, but at least it protects the code as it was written originally - whatever that gets someone)

Comment: @Grismar Well, *it is* a question, im not using this for actual distribution, just asking if its possible.

Comment: In programming the answer to the question if any that seems doable "is possible", is generally 'yes', but it's the wrong question. The question should be "is it a good idea, what does it cost, and who needs it?"

Answer (score 0):

You can just prevent the error altogether by using `try` and `except`

```
try:
   print("hello"f)
except:
   print("found error");
```

Now, as you can see, there is an error on the first line, and when ever python interpreter finds that error, instead of calling a traceback, it just runs the code in the `except` block...

Comment: No, this only works for runtime errors, it's of no use with a SyntaxError since no code actually gets executed.

Comment: What i am looking for is the normal error message, but not showing the line of code that caused the problem. Your question just suppresses the error message (Also doing ```"str"f ```is a error that is not suppressed by ```try```)

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote helper function `ExcText()`, you can see how I used it inside `test()` function. If you call it as `ExcText(False)` then lines of code are not printed, if `ExcText(True)` then they are printed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFBT8MwDIXv/ApzasKqHuA2iSOI@yZxGFOVdS4LS50q8bT11xe3YYtYDlXTZ/t9z@0HPnh6Gcc9tvB2adZ4YRUP/lw7Sxj18gHk2K73gSEOsQQOpsGdaY6zEuA1f6lWLM/VqetMGCqZJAKrLJ@NO9a8UzJH1Ka21HqlN89brZNNC@TF5maf3KfT@gC2BARLgHTqMBhGFXSumGk2dlvNrYJVFIkQ@RRIbtWPt6Q2xfrKA6rzkaWgQWJojHPgTGS9/KJiCwsIlbh2hpWGxc0mp0liLUGwZ@up9uQG9XQXbjmne5jWyxhlViLmMGT0SfxWd1lMjCg7fzcuYgnFBzrnS/j0we0fi3@t7X2rzMqL@3tPmLmuD5ZYXf/47DJxJsZx/AU)

```py
def ExcText(show_lines):
    import sys, traceback
    r = traceback.StackSummary.extract(traceback.walk_tb(sys.exc_info()[2]))
    if not show_lines:
        for i, e in enumerate(r):
            r[i]._line = ''
    return ''.join(['Traceback (most recent call last):\n'] + r.format() +
        traceback.format_exception_only(*sys.exc_info()[:2]))

def test():
    try:
        def g():
            assert False, 'Hello, World!'
        def f():
            g()
        f()
    except:
        print(ExcText(False))

test()
```

Output for `ExcText(False)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\t\test.py", line 16, in test
  File "C:\t\test.py", line 15, in f
  File "C:\t\test.py", line 13, in g
AssertionError: Hello, World!
```

Output for `ExcText(True)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\t\test.py", line 16, in test
    f()
  File "C:\t\test.py", line 15, in f
    g()
  File "C:\t\test.py", line 13, in g
    assert False, 'Hello, World!'
AssertionError: Hello, World!
```

You can also use code above to catch Syntax Errors, just do `compile(program_text, '<string>', 'exec')`, where program text is a string containing text of script that needs to be checked, example of [code is here](https://tio.run/##XVJBcoMwDLznFbrZbhkO7Y1pe2s/kNwowzhUEDdgM7aYhNdTgZOQxgeP7JW0u7L7kQ7Ovk7TD9bwea52eCYZDu5UtsZiSMAN1A9UdqGBd9j5AVW2AV6m650nCCPnkNcV7nV1XBDPibebdEu8b4eu035MuTkDJFf4pNtjSXvJfRitSmNrJ1X@UigVaWqwjmluiiL7vGrnwSSAYCygHTr0mlB6tWYsanJTpEspyxIiKkQavOVT@uuMlbnYXfWA7FwgTqjQElS6baHVgVT2bUUBz@BTZu00SXUjeYY7OxEt2Qn2ZJwtnW1H@fTgLmN7s7O72WIbEPIitlWbzfwchIGJss1y13vXLA7Egh3kxWfvjSVZi1g5w0tAflznMBc08mEwlet606KcGycg3gJxp@ZDcIxnrIT6V14/ljd3I6gvcbS95kVt11/1pdljEv8QO4zupukP). You may also read program text from file through:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    prog = f.read()
```

You should use `compile()` instead of `exec()` when you only need syntax check, because script (program text) may contain some malicious code (like trojan) and `exec()` will execute it after checking syntax, while `compile()` will not execute, just checks that it is compilable and has no syntax errors.

---

Also non-printing of code lines can be achieved by hack with patching `linecache.getline()` function, like below.

But beware that this solution modifies standard module, so it is a hack that should be avoided if possible. First solution above is better.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU@7DsIwDNz7FWYKVFUXtkqsiD9gRG7qPkSaRIkH@vUh6VNw053tu5PtxL3R1xAaaoHJ8/lSZRAxjNY4BnYoqUb5noe7KtWgSaLsqeyIk4AbKBzrBiG36DpfQJ7rRCoQYjavCdOSn5A6u61wA3pPsfiOylMB4kFKmQKexqnmJH6s7b81Zu26XTl9JFk@7o4XrBs0v@I@XmbL61kIXw)

```py
def test():
    import traceback
    traceback.linecache.getline = lambda *pargs, **nargs: ''
    
    try:
        def g():
            assert False, 'Hello, World!'
        def f():
            g()
        f()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()

test()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\t\test.py", line 10, in test
  File "C:\t\test.py", line 9, in f
  File "C:\t\test.py", line 7, in g
AssertionError: Hello, World!
```

Comment: It's okay, But it does not work for Syntax errors. Good enough!

Comment: @Allearthstuffs Syntax error can be catched too I wrote [example here](https://tio.run/##XVJBboMwELzzir1hNxGH9obUY/uB5EYQcuhC3Bgb2YsSXk8XnIQ0PiDbM7szs7gf6eTsxzT9YANf13qPVxLh5C6V0RbDFtxA/UBVF1r4hL0fUOYJ8NJd7zxBGJlDXtV4VPV5QTwTHzfZjvi7G7pO@THj5gyQWOGLMueKjoL7MFpX2jZOyOK9lDLKNGAdyzwcRfV5Nc6D3gKCtoB26NArQuHlyljcFLrMllK2labRIdLgLZ@yX6etKNL93Q@IzgViQo2WoFbGgFGBZH6waQkb8BmrdoqEfIhs4ClORCtOgj1pZytnzSjeXtLlHG9O9jRbNAGhKGNbmSTz7yAMLJQny13vXbskSBfsJG45e68tiSaNlTO8bMiP6xzmgla8DAavWIu5q/zHa1557VPW5raP@VZeNHF/Pt@Kw2zjY@EoMcY0/QE), notice,I used `print(ExcText(False, True))`, try also `ExcText(False, False)`

Comment: @Allearthstuffs In example from previous comment above I used `prog = '''...'''` as inline string inside code, you may also read it from text file as `prog = open(filename, encoding = 'utf-8').read()`.

Comment: @Allearthstuffs If my answer was correct and/or helpful, don't forget to Accept and/or UpVote it. Accepting and UpVoting is done at the top of my answer to the left handside, there is upper-arrow (upper-triangle) for UpVoting and Check-Mark for accepting. Accepting means that answer correctly solves your task. UpVoting means that you Liked the answer. Both UpVoting and Accepting can be done same time, both of them give me (author of answer) extra scores to raise my reputation.

Comment: Well, i guess it's impossible (edit: maybe possible from @Charles Duffy 's comment on the question) to avoid *all* lines not being shown, because your code on the website (output of it [thats on the website]) (error message) does not show the function names but does show ```print(f')```

Comment: @Allearthstuffs In your previous comment you forgot to add link with website output.

Comment: @Allearthstuffs Can you show output with my special function and without it? Also did you try second solution with `linecache` patching that I showed in my answer?

Comment: @Allearthstuffs Just updated part of my answer, where I told to use `exec()` before, I changed my mind - you have to use `compile()` instead, beceause exec executes code if syntax check was successful. And you may have some malicious code there (like trojan). Hence use `compile()` to only check syntax without executing. See my updated answer!